# arduino digital pins do not work

Tags: arduino

The digital pins in arduino suddenly died. I was work on a project and every thing was good I don't know what is the problem with this and what is cause it. 
Please anyone can help me to know the problem and why? and if it can repair.

Comment: Can you please provide more details and examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can set those pins to high and then check with voltmeter if they are showing a voltage of approx. 5V, otherwise they may be dead
You can replace the main controller in your arduino board in some cases like Arduino uno.